# Flash Video in full screen system failure

Tags: nvidia, hardware, flash, fullscreen

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and replaced hard drives and video cards (both nvidia) but changed drivers as I went from a 7600gt with the 173 driver to GT 640 with 310 driver. I had some success before (only HD videos would cause this issue) and now it is easily repeatable for me regardless of other circumstances.

1. Open browser of choice (tested Opera, Chromium, Firefox, Chrome) to flash content
2. Play flash content in full screen
3. Watch PC shut off from failure

I can play Team Fortress 2 in HD 1080p. I can watch 1080p content from enormous MKV files or HTML5 from Youtube. I can play flash content in 720p from a VM on the PC and not have any issues so I don't think it is a power supply issue or a PC hardware issue.

However, something is amiss and I cannot find this issue anywhere. Help would be appreciated. It is something that (while it can be lived with) is annoying to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

OK. So, constant digging has actually yielded some results. In order to get the full screen option working (requiring GPU scaling and thus video acceleration) requires VDPAU installed.

Tried the method listed here: http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=4232.0 and after restarting the apps it seems to have settled the issue out and I have not had a new incident since installing. Also I have been running video for 10 minutes without issue. Hope this proves useful to someone later. Thanks for the help troubleshooting.